# How can I "filter" a ManyToMany child in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

#### First some context

I am working on a corporate application, in this application a user can have access to multiple companies.
The same user can be assigned to **one** employee in **each** company. To prevent the user from creating multiple user accounts, the user will be "connected" to a company and "company employee" via pivot tables.

#### The problem

I have a Company model in laravel with a `users()` attribute, this works as expected (because it returns all the users connected to the business via the pivot table).

In my User model I have an `employee()` attribute, this returns **all** the employees linked to the user via the pivot table, including the employees that are not linked to the requested business / do not have the same business_fk value as the requested Business ID.

I need to get the single employee that is connected to the requested business and user via the pivot tables.

So I think I need to filter the User -> Employee relation by the `business_fk` key in the `users()` attribute in the Company model, but I don't know how.

**Model: Company**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_employee_pivot', 'employee_fk', 'user_fk')
    ->withPivot('ID');
}
```

**Model: User**

```
public function employee()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class, 'user_employee_pivot', 'user_fk', 'employee_fk')
    ->withPivot('ID');
}
```

#### Simplified table structure

```
TABLE users
ID           PK INT
username     STRING

--------

TABLE company
ID      PK INT
name    STRING

--------

TABLE employee
ID          PK INT
fullname    STRING
company_fk  FK INT (referencing to company table PK)

--------

TABLE user_business_pivot
ID            PK INT
user_fk       FK INT (referencing to user table PK)
company_fk    FK INT (referencing to company table PK)

--------

TABLE user_employee_pivot
ID            PK INT
user_fk       FK INT (referencing to user table PK)
employee_fk   FK INT (referencing to employee table PK)
```

If I'm not clear enough, please let me know. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Did my answer help you or do you still have problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Employees you can fetch, by filtering the relationship, since it is `belongsToMany` employee should be employees.

```
public function getEmployeesByCompany(User $user, Company $company) {
    return $user->employees()->where('company_fk', $company->id)->get();
}
```

This method could easily be done on the user model or similar, this is just an example.